# Como utilizar RAII, Construtores e Exceções

Tags: c++, exceção, construtor

Eu sou novo em C++ e recentemente me deparei com algo que eu não consigo entender muito bem, qual seja: nas minhas pesquisas, eu vi que o RAII é uma técnica adequada para ser utilizada quando se precisa adquirir um recurso no construtor e destruir automaticamente no destrutor.

Nessas mesmas pesquisas, aprendi também que o RAII é muito utilizado com exceções e afirma-se com frequência que as exceções são a principal maneira de se lidar com erros em construtores já que eles não retornam valor.

Contudo, nessas minhas pesquisas que envolveram uma dúzia de sites e alguns livros, eu não vi um exemplo que envolvesse um RAII, no qual o construtor lançasse uma exceção. E quando eu tentei eu mesmo fazer isso, as coisas simplesmente não funcionaram.

Abaixo, as minhas tentativas (eu vou utilizar como exemplo de recurso adquirido no construtor o ponteiro para a `struct SDL_Surface*` da biblioteca SDL, que eu estou mais familiarizado):

```
#include <SDL.h>
#include <SDL_image.h>
#include <iostream>

class Surface {

private:
    SDL_Surface* surface_;
public:
    Surface(std::string path) {

        surface_ = IMG_Load(path.c_str());
        if (!surface_) {
            throw std::runtime_error("unable to load file.\n");
        }
    }
    ~Surface() {
        if (surface_) {
            SDL_FreeSurface(surface_);
        }
    }
    SDL_Surface* getSurface() {
        return surface_;
    }
};

int main(int argc, char* args[]) {


    SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_VIDEO);

    std::string file_path = "foo.png";

    try {
        Surface foo_surface(file_path);     
    }
    catch (std::runtime_error &e) {
        std::cerr << "Caught a runtime_error exception: "
            << e.what() << '\n';

    }

    //agora ao tentar usar foo_surface, não é possível pois a variável saiu do escopo ao
    //final do bloco try    
    int largura = foo_surface.getSurface()->h;
    int altura = foo_surface.getSurface()->w;

    return 0;
}
```

Ou seja, nesta primeira tentativa, as coisas não funcionaram porque `foo_surface` perdeu o escopo ao final do bloco `try{}` e, naturalmente, o compilador reclama: `“identifier ‘foo_surface’ is undefined”`.

Para tentar contornar isso, uma segunda tentativa com algumas modificações (exibido apenas a função `main()`):

```
int main(int argc, char* args[]) {


    SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_VIDEO);

    std::string file_path = "foo.png";
    Surface* foo_surface = nullptr;

    try {
        foo_surface = new Surface("foo.png");       
    }
    catch (std::runtime_error &e) {
        std::cerr << "Caught a runtime_error exception: "
            << e.what() << '\n';

        return -1;  
    }

    //até aqui as coisas funcionam bem, mas...
    int largura = foo_surface->getSurface()->h;
    int altura = foo_surface->getSurface()->w;

    //eu preciso deletar foo_surface no final do escopo.
    delete foo_surface;

    return 0;
}
```

O código funciona (e compila), mas o problema é que agora eu preciso deletar `foo_surface` no final do escopo. E porque isso é um problema? Como, a única razão para eu criar uma classe, foi a possibilidade de o destrutor liberar automaticamente a memória quando o objeto perdesse o escopo, com a necessidade de deletar o objeto eu perco a minha motivação original e, obviamente, se for para usar delete, é muito mais fácil simplesmente abandonar o gerenciamento automático da memória e ficar com a solução sem o uso de classe, construtor, destrutor e exceção, a qual consiste em:

```
int main(int argc, char* args[]) {

    SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_VIDEO);

    SDL_Surface* foo_surface = IMG_Load("foo.png");
    if (!foo_surface) {
        std::cerr << "Unable to load image.\n";
        return -1;
    }

    int largura = foo_surface ->w;
    int altura = foo_surface->h;

    SDL_FreeSurface(foo_surface);

    return 0;
}
```

Enfim, como eu li muito que RAII e exceções são comumente usadas juntas, como eu não vi nenhum exemplo prático disso, e como a minha tentativa de usar ambas as coisas em conjunto simplesmente não funcionou como indicado acima, a impressão que eu tenho é que eu estou deixando alguma coisa muito básica escapar.

Então, as minhas dúvidas são:

1. as minhas abordagens foram corretas ou eu estou cometendo um erro muito grande de principiante?
2. E como compatibilizar o gerenciamento automático de memória proporcionado pelo RAII com exceções lançadas pelo construtor, dado o problema do escopo do bloco `try{}`;

Por fim, eu não sou programador, na verdade, eu comecei a estudar C++ há um ano mais ou menos, por simples curiosidade e (adorei programação), então peço desculpas pelos inúmeros erros conceituais, terminológicos e de codificação que eu devo ter cometido nessa pergunta.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O modo mais [*RAII*](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aquisi%C3%A7%C3%A3o_de_Recurso_%C3%A9_Inicializa%C3%A7%C3%A3o) para o seu segundo caso, possivelmente é o uso de [smart pointers](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ponteiro_inteligente)<sup>[3](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48719831/10707951)</sup>, 
como `std::unique_ptr` e `std::share_ptr`, mas me parece que você está com medo de usar o corpo do try.

Como você deve **evitar alocação de heap**<sup>[4](https://www.quora.com/Is-the-stack-faster-than-the-heap-If-so-why-Why-isn%E2%80%99t-memory-allocation-needed-for-stack-Why-can%E2%80%99t-a-compiler-know-where-an-object-is-in-heap/answer/Gregory-Popovitch)</sup>, a melhor saída é algo como:

```
try {
    // cria
    Surface foo_surface(file_path);

    // aqui eh garantido o uso do recurso adquirido
    int largura = foo_surface.getSurface()->h;
    int altura = foo_surface.getSurface()->w;

    // faco algo legal com a minha largura e altura (adquiridas)
}
catch (std::runtime_error &e) {
    std::cerr << "Caught a runtime_error exception: " << e.what() << '\n';
}
```

Para isso é bom ter em mente que exeções antes disparadas, pois estavam fora do `try`, agora serão pegas e tratadas igual ao erro de inicialização/aquisição, e não mais disparadas.

A solução é ter uma **tipagem forte de exceções**, ou pelo menos:

```
try {/*cria e usa*/}
catch (InitError &) {/*erro iniciando*/}
catch(ExecError &) {/*erro usando*/}
catch(...) {/*erro nao esperado*/}
```

Mas **use o corpo do *try* livremente**, claro, tentando se ater ao escopo do recurso adquirido (objeto criado):

```
try {
    /*cria*/ 
    try { /*usa*/ }catch(...){/*erro usando*/}
}
catch(...) {/*erro iniciando*/}
```

Comment: Entendi. A sua resposta faz todo o sentido e resolveu outros problemas. Quer dizer, mesmo no segundo exemplo o único tratamento que eu consegui dar para a exceção foi o encerramento do programa, do contrário, _foo_surface_ poderia não ter sido inicializado e ocorreria um erro na linha `int largura = foo_surface ->w;` e na linha seguinte. Bem, eu aceitei a resposta, acho que eu entendi o que eu estava deixando escapar, dei upvote também, mas não aparece porque eu não tenho reputação para isso. Vlw.